# How is one to thoroughly test iOS apps with all the various devices of different screen size?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I started out iOS development 4 years ago when there was only two screen sizes to worry about. The 3.5" (non-retina) iPhone and the 9.7" iPad. One of the reasons that I chose iOS development was because unlike Android OS development at the time, there was only two screen sizes to design for making it simple to ensure that all my apps would look good on all devices.

I am the kind of person that likes to make sure everything is perfect before releasing my application. So, I believe that if you've only tested your app out on the simulator (of which there was only like 4 options, two versions iOS for the iPad and 2 for the iPhone) then your app is not ready for the big time because code runs differently on the actual device itself. So, four years ago, I got an iPad and began to test my applications on that as well.

However, this is where the issue (and the question) really comes in. Now theres 2 or three different size iPhones and like 5 different size iPads. I can't very well buy one of each (nor do I want to) so what do you guys recommend would be the best way to test my apps on-device for all these various screen sizes?

Comment: ethan, I removed the unrelated question from your question. Feel free to ask other separate questions.

Comment: A little OT, but it does seem that there's a market for testing services in the mobile world.

Comment: Hi Philip -of course there are many testing services, there are hundreds of well-known companies that do this.

Comment: Except for the upcoming iPad Pro, there's really only one sized iPad (in points) and it's 1024x768. Of course there are retina and non-retina versions of that one resolution and there are "normal" and "mini" physical sized versions of that one resolution. But all are the same resolution in points. But there are 4 different iPhone sizes: 3.5", 4", 4.7", and 5.5" each with a different resolution.

Comment: Test on as many devices as you can physically. The remaining devices, test on their respective simulators. Cross fingers. Pray. Check crash logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy used devices on eBay. Buy devices with small damages. iPhone 6 with cracked screen is quite affordable on eBay :-) For iPads, don't worry about the mini, it is just a shrunk version of the larger one and behaves identically (alternatively, buy the iPad Mini and don't worry about the larger one, saving money).

Use layout constraints, and use the simulator. If you really don't want to release unless it is tested on a real device, just don't support the bigger sizes. Your code can easily treat a 6 or 6+ as a "large iPhone 5".

Comment: It's an excellent point. In fact when you have an unlimited budget, it is common to buy **old devices on eBay** because you need those as well, and they are hard to get otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, larger companies and studios have a number of each device. That's all there is to it.  For most developers, it comes down to **you buy each new iPhone and iPad that comes out**.

In that way you have at least one of everything in stock, over time.

There's really no alternative to this. App development is expensive.

It's worth noting that if your studio develops for Android, the situation is worse! Although the following article is a little old, it's still the case

http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/11/this-is-what-developing-for-android-looks-like/

[image]

No difference in the iOS universe.

*"I can't very well buy one of each..."* Unfortunately you have to. It's the cost of doing this business.

*"I can't very well buy one of each (nor do I want to)"*  Unfortunately you have to. It's the cost of doing this business.

It's perhaps worth noting that: the cost of being a developer is "A few thousand a year" for devices and a few thousand a year for hardware (Macs, etc) and the inevitable licenses (Unity3D, etc). It's perhaps worth noting that: relative to almost any other business, this is extremely low.

Note that a couple of people have jokingly replied, "just use the simulator and hope!" Obviously that's a non-starter.

Comment: Obviously it is not a real substitute but what about testing in the simulator at different screen sizes?  If it's only to make sure the interface looks right, would that be enough?

Comment: How about, "I want to be a truck driver, so I'll buy one of every kind of truck on the market"?

Comment: Don't blame me; it's your analogy.  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Thats a very poor analogy:   
"I can't very well buy one of each..." It would be like saying you want to be a truck driver, but you "can't buy" a truck.    

How is that like acquiring iOS Devices? In your example they only buy one truck so if you apply it to an iOS device it would be like saying "I can't very well buy one of each.." and then they buy 1 device and that satisfies all their needs. It won't. It would be more like "I own the truck which is like my app but need to acquire all the different trailer types to test its compatibility".

Comment: Hi Polar. The analogy is you need to spend a certain amount of money to have a given business.  I'm happy to change the analogy in the QA, cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way! I created a small open source project called Screen Sizes Simulator. It uses a resizable embedded view which allows you to change the size of your app during runtime. You can test all iPhone sizes on your iPad, switching freely between sizes during runtime.

You can event test different iPhone sizes in smaller iPhones! Using the "Zoom to Fit" option you can even run an app with the iPhone 6 aspect ration in an iPhone...

You can find the project on GitHub: [Screen Sizes Simulator](https://github.com/felipeferri/ScreenSizesSimulator)

Here's an example screenshot of an app using the Screen Sizes Simulator:

[image]